# Table Field Factory for a Transient variable

Tags: java, vaadin

I'd like to create a custom column for my vaadin table. All items should have a column with a checkbox. In order to have this column, I created a transient variable, which name is "selected". When the table makes its columns, the `table.setTableFieldFactory()` runs, but "selected" is not presented in the propertyIds' list.

```
table.setTableFieldFactory((container, itemId, propertyId, uiContext) -> {
        if("selected".equals(propertyId)) {
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> selectListener((Boolean)event.getProperty().getValue()));
            return checkBox;
        }
        return null;
    });
```

The questions are, how to create a custom field for transient variable? How should I add my transient variable to propertyIds' list? What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you create your transient variable? What type of container do you have? What is the result?

Comment: its playframework so i created it in my model with javax.persistence.transient annotation. Its an JPAContainer and the result is TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JPAContainer, but I find some interesting page: [link1](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/2482838), [link2](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12861).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was wrong. This table was a CustomTable, which was made by my mate. It has a column generator on Boolean.class. So when it was making the columns, its overwrote my definition.